# How much space does each active user consume in the sharepoint database?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

This is only a discussion.How much space does each active user consume in the database? The assumption is that when a user is active the user is able to log into the SharePoint server.If a user is not active, then only the history data would be left on the database.

Comment: What do you base this assumption on? And what do you mean by "when a user is active, the user is able to *log into the SharePoint server*."? If a user is active, s/he is already logged in. This question does not make sense.

Comment: i mean when we add a user to sharepoint site

Comment: Sorry, but you really need to provide some more context about the issue and what you are trying to achieve. How do you "add a user"?

Comment: I have so many users in my active directory.I am adding user to my sharepoint site.Then there will be entries in sharepoint content db.I want to know how much space(in bytes or kb's) in database it needed.

Comment: `I have so many users in my active directory` - How many? | `I am adding user to my sharepoint site` - How? Add them to a group? Add an AD group to a SP group? | `Then there will be entries in sharepoint content db` - What entries? In what content db? | `I want to know how much space(in bytes or kb's) in database it needed` - Why does it matter? Why is it an issue? Are you short in SQL db space? If so, the whole user management probably takes less space than an uploaded PowerPoint deck with an embedded video. Why the concern? Is is just academic? Or is there a business limitation?

Comment: You did not answer any of the questions for clarification. It does not matter if this is for a client of for your own site.  The system suggests that this discussion be moved to chat but you don't have enough reputation to participate in chat. Please edit your question and provide more detail, otherwise nobody will be able to help you. If you are working as a SharePoint consultant you should be able to provide the detail required to flesh out the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only significant space usage is from the User Profile Application Service, which uses an estimated 1MB per user. Profile sync is another 600KB and social tagging will add 0.009MB per tag, comment or rating.

Source: Core Solutions of Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013